# How to dynamically generate SQL query column names and values from arrays?

Tags: sql, go

I have about 20 columns in one row and not all columns are required to be filled in when row created also i dont want to cardcode name of every column in SQL query and on http.post request on frontend. All values are from form. My code:

```
var colNames, values []string

for k, v := range formData {
    colNames = append(colNames, k)
    values = append(values, v)
}
```

Now i have 2 arrays: one with column names and second with values to be inserted. I want to do something like this:

```
db.Query("insert into views (?,?,?,?,?,?) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", colNames..., values...)
```

or like this:

```
db.Query("insert into views " + colNames + " values" + values)
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: are you using mysql?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mysql

Comment: One of these tools should help you https://github.com/variadico/scaneo or https://github.com/drone/sqlgen but looks like they don't have support :(

Comment: @YandryPozo thanks for this tools, but i was looking for something simple. Anyway I will keep this repos in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your code examples are just pseudo code but I'll state the obvious just in case.

```
db.Query("insert into views (?,?,?,?,?,?) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", colNames..., values...)
```

This is invalid Go since you can only "unpack" the last argument to a function, and also invalid MySQL since you cannot use placeholders (`?`) for column names.

```
db.Query("insert into views " + colNames + " values" + values)
```

This is also invalid Go since you cannot concatenate strings with slices.

---

You could fromat the slices into strings that look like this:

```
colNamesString := "(col1, col2, col3)"
valuesString   := "(val1, val2, val3)"
```

and now your second code example becomes valid Go and would compile **but don't do this.** If you do this your app becomes vulnerable to SQL injection and that's something you definitely don't want.

---

Instead do something like this:

```
// this can be a package level global and you'll need
// one for each table. Keep in mind that Go maps that
// are only read from are safe for concurrent use.
var validColNames = map[string]bool{
     "col1": true,
     "col2": true,
     "col3": true,
     // ...
}

// ...

var colNames, values []string
var phs string // placeholders for values

for k, v := range formData {
    // check that column is valid
    if !validColNames[k] {
        return ErrBadColName
    }
    colNames = append(colNames, k)
    values = append(values, v)
    phs += "?,"
}

if len(phs) > 0 {
    phs = phs[:len(phs)-1] // drop the last comma
}
phs = "(" + phs + ")"

colNamesString := "(" + strings.Join(colNames, ",") + ")"
query := "insert into views " + colNamesString + phs
db.Query(query, values...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking about solution like this.